# How to set date attribute filter to current month in microstrategy dossier

Tags: microstrategy

I want to add the date attribute to filter. The display style of the date must be in calendar form.
By default from date must be set to 1st date of the current month.
By default To date must be current date.

Please let me know how to set the from  date to 1st of current month by default please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the dynamic date, by default it would be the current date.
[image]